# Django: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static' when trying to upload image through admin when deployed through Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, image-uploading

I have my app deployed on Heroku using MySQL database. I am trying to upload an image using the admin interface, but am getting the following error:

```
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static'
```

I can upload images just fine locally. How can I write files to this folder, as to upload images? Here are my static settings and Image model field currently:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'media')

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='')
```

I believe it should default upload to the media folder by default. `DEBUG` is set to True.

Comment: Change permissions on that folder on prod server may be?

Comment: For some reason you don't define MEDIA_ROOT - which is where files are uploaded to - if DEBUG is not true. But even if you could make this part of it work, the actual functionality wouldn't work, because *you cannot store things on the filesystem in Heroku*; it is ephemeral and isn't shared between dynos. Use a permanent external storage system like S3.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into external storage then.

Answer (score 0):

as quoted by @Daniel Roseman:

> You cannot store things on the filesystem in Heroku; it is ephemeral and isn't shared between dynos. Use a permanent external storage system like S3.